# How to stub an inner function and set a variable value

Tags: node.js, testing, sinon, stub, sinon-chai

This is one of the more complex scenarios I've encountered yet. I have a function that I need to test, this function is nested in a complex puzzle of functions. I need to stub this function, and set a value inside the `variable` inside.

For reasons I'm not allowed to share here, the variable inside the `publishEvent()` method is undefined during test run, I need a way to set the value for this variable during test in order for me to test the if block of code in the function.

I summarized the whole file because I can't share the code here due to NDA, sorry if the question is not detailed enough. Maybe using sinon I can directly set the value for this variable in the `publishEvent` function.

```js
function emitEvent() {
    async function publishEvent() {
        const variable = library.fetchData()

        if (variable) {
            // do something
        }
    }

    return Promise.resolve(publishEvent())
            .then(() => { })
            .catch(() => null);
}

function requestSuscription() {
    return getAllSubscriptions()
        .then((results) => {
            return Promise.map(results, () => emitEvent())
        })
}

function getAllSubscriptions() {
    return new Promise()
}

function requestOtherSubscription() {
    console.log('other thing requested')
}

module.exports = { requestSuscription, requestOtherSubscription }
```

I know I can stub the `requestSuscription`, `requestOtherSubscription` functions and it works, but how can I stub the `publishEvent` and set the variable value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need a way of controlling what `library.fetchData()` outputs. Either you need a way of [injecting a substitute](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70903374/200987) for that library (easiest option) or you need to [employ a link seam](https://sinonjs.org/how-to/link-seams-commonjs/) (environment dependant, requires extra lib) - substituting the library with a fake one at the module loading level.

You can check out this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70895476/200987) to a nearly identical question for details.